# Java NIO or Java IO for high performance server

Tags: java, sockets, io, nio

I have been struggling for a while choosing between java NIO, or the old java i/o blocking sockets, for a server i am developing.

I was thinking that java NIO would be better, because it will have a very large number of clients, and the clients will stay connected so the server can push data when available.

SO this makes me think that java blocking i/o will be overkill, as the number of threads will be high.

What is your opinion, for this case?

Comment: Have you tried [netty](https://netty.io/)?

Comment: I would use an *existing* framework - don't use NIO directly, it's a PITA and hard to "get correct" - at the very least use a wrapper for it like XNIO, although perhaps even a higher-level abstraction would be a start (e.g. a message framework or an event-driven server as Tomasz mentioned). To me, a big advantage of NIO isn't so much "thread reduction" as it is "concurrency reduction" - that is, it requires me to think less about concurrency issues by having a single cross-point between threads.

Comment: What do you mean by a high number of connections? 100, 1000, 10000 or 100,000 per server. Your solution will depend on what your exact requirements are. Without more detail I would assume the simpler solution is best.

Answer (score 1):

You would only have a problem with blocking I/O if the push of a single message to a client was expected to take a long time. Just having the clients connected does not entail one thread per client. In fact, I am right now writing such a piece of software. You only need as many threads as there are concurrent message pushes going on at a particular point in time. This will normally not be high. Consider the ratio of time needed to push a message against the wait time for a message to arrive. Multiply the number of simultaneous clients with this number and you have your average active thread count.

You'll be maintaining a set of all open output streams, one for each client. They will just be sitting in memory until a message arrives that needs to be pushed to a client. At that point you'll need one thread to handle that one message. If, while the message is being pushed, you want to handle another event and push a message to another client, you'll need a second thread, but as soon as the first push is done, that thread is returned to the pool of available threads.

I can also advise an actor model implementation to coordinate your message pushing. The actor model is the exact match for this problem.